# Set a Progress Bar in DataGridView in VB.net

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, datagridview, progress-bar

**I want to set a Progress bar while this datagrid is importing records from a excel file, some excel files are bigger, and it takes a time to import to the datagrid, so i need the progress bar to see the progress, well**

```
Private Sub openFileButton_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles openFileButton.Click

    Dim OpenFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog

    OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
    OpenFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|XLS Files (*.xls)|*xls"


    If (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then

        Dim fi As New FileInfo(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
        Dim FileName As String = OpenFileDialog.FileName

        excel = fi.FullName
        conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [Sheet1$]", conn)
        dts = New DataSet

        dta.Fill(dts, "[Sheet1$]")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dts
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "[Sheet1$]"
        conn.Close()

    End If
    Dim GridTotal As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count
    TextBox1.Text = GridTotal.ToString
End Sub
```

**This code works perfect for me, just need and Example for the ProgressBar**

Comment: There is nothing to count so there is no progress to report.  Use Marquee style

Comment: Of course there is something to count, by the columns updated from the excel file to the DGV, using 'Each' code and set it a range, so it makes a loop for columns and adds a percent to the progress bar until it reaches the range, anyway, thanks.

Comment: `I want to set a Progress bar while this datagrid is importing records from a excel file`  that will happen en masse with the `dta.Fill` line.  When it is done its done.  Nothing will happen to tell you `row x of y` done; hence there is no counting going on in that code.